# Can the C# compiler easily be changed to let enum types implement the generic IEquatable`1 and IComparable`1 interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I wrote the following method:

```
public static T Max<T>(T x, T y) where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
  return (x.CompareTo(y) > 0) ? x : y;
}
```

This works great and finds the larger of two value-type values. Here's an example where it's used:

```
void Test(DateTime oneTime, DateTime anotherTime)
{
  var latestTime = Max(oneTime, anotherTime);
  ...
}
```

But the above method doesn't work for enums. So e.g. `Max(DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday)` won't work because of the constraint (compiler: `"There is no boxing conversion from 'System.DayOfWeek' to 'System.IComparable<System.DayOfWeek>'."`).

There are of course work-arounds. I could make the constraint refer to the non-generic interface, but that would involve **boxing** of `y` to `System.Object` in the `CompareTo` call. And who likes non-generic .NET 1 interfaces?

`DayOfWeek` **does** implement the non-generic interface `IComparable` (through the base class `System.Enum` of any enumeration type), but sadly `DayOfWeek` does not implement `IComparable<DayOfWeek>`.

So my question is: Would it be difficult to change this situation (in a future .NET release) so that a C# declaration like `enum MyFoo { ... }` gives a type that implements `IComparable<MyFoo>` and `IEquatable<MyFoo>`?

(When they introduced .NET 2, they made magic to have a `T[]` implement `IList<T>` even if `System.Array` is non-generic. My "request" seems easier (`System.Enum` is also non-generic, but the user-defined enum is a "real" type).)

Comment: Not sure if this is a change to C#, or rather one to the CLR or BCL.

Comment: Try posting this as a suggestion on Microsoft.Connect.

Comment: IComparable<T> is for when you want to compare something to a different type, as this generic only compares 2 parameters of the same type it would never need IComparable<T>... Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, it looks like this is not the correct place to ask why the authors of .NET 2 and C# 2 chose not to make enums `IEquatable<>`, since they closed my qustion. It would have been useful, though, if they were. Is there anothor Stack Exchange Network where this is ontopic?

Comment: @PeterWishart Yes, you misunderstand. The generic `IComparable<T>` is exactly to ensure that only "similar" objects are compared. With the non-generic interface, this will compile (but explode run-time): `IComparable c = DayOfWeek.Thursday; c.CompareTo(StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: @PeterWishart `IComparable<T>` is for comparing objects of the same type. For example in ordered collections.

Comment: You could, more practically, have an "enum" pattern where you're free to implement the interface. Look [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/fixing-the-enum-in-c/240004191) for the idea.